# Struggling with microdata

Tags: asp.net, microdata

I want to use microdata for a SoftwareApplication to express both SoftwareVersion, Offers and DownloadUrl properties in a single sentence. The text on my website the reads as :
"Latest version is 7.0.5.0 which can be downloaded for free here."

The master page already contains many attributes for SoftwareApplication and the
asp code for the above sentence - which is wrong actually - is as follows:

```
<div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
  <meta itemprop="price" content="0" />
  <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="USD" />
  <p style="font-weight: bold; color: #6800ff; text-align: center;">Latest version is <span itemprop="softwareVersion">7.0.5.0</span> which can be downloaded for <span itemprop="description">free</span> <a itemprop="downloadUrl" href="http://www.prettygoodterminal.com/download/freedownload.zip">here.</a></p>
</div>
```

The problem is, that this way the softwareVersion and downloadurl properties are interpreted as an element in offers, which is invalid. [image: Structured Data Analyzis]

How can I avoid this issue and use properties from different elements - that is, from both SoftwareApplication and Offers - in a single literal sentence ?

Comment: Can you move the sentence (or the `Offer`) away? Or does the sentence need to be a descendant of the element with the `Offer` itemscope?

Answer (score 0):

What you want is not possible with the current workings of the microdata standard.

I can think of 2 possible ways to deal with this

#### 1. Use `itemref`

This requires a more intrusive change in the HTML layout because your `SoftwareApplication` needs to know the `id`'s used in the nested `Offer`.

This will connect the `downloadUrl` and `softwareVersion` `itemprop`'s to the `SoftwareApplication`, but the connection with the `Offer` will stay in place. There is no way to break this inheritance at the moment.

The Google validator *will keep complaining* that those properties are not known part of `Offer`, but the values are now part of the `SoftwareApplication`.

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/SoftwareApplication" itemref="appversion appurl">
  <meta itemprop="applicationCategory" content="Game" />
  <meta itemprop="operatingSystem" content="Windows" />
    <div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
      <meta itemprop="price" content="0" />
      <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="USD" />
      <p>Latest version is <span itemprop="softwareVersion" id="appversion">7.0.5.0</span> which can be downloaded for <span itemprop="description">free</span> <a itemprop="downloadUrl" id="appurl" href="http://www.prettygoodterminal.com/download/freedownload.zip">here</a>.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### 2. Use duplicate, implicit values

This is the smallest change, but duplicates the values in the HTML.

Just add the values to the right scope, without being visible to the user, using the `meta` and `link` tags.

Remove the `itemprop`'s from the content inside the `Offer`.

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/SoftwareApplication">
  <meta itemprop="applicationCategory" content="Game" />
  <meta itemprop="operatingSystem" content="Windows" />
  <meta itemprop="softwareVersion" content="7.0.5.0" />
  <link itemprop="downloadUrl" href="http://www.prettygoodterminal.com/download/freedownload.zip" />
  <div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
      <meta itemprop="price" content="0" />
      <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="USD" />
      <p>Latest version is 7.0.5.0 which can be downloaded for <span itemprop="description">free</span> <a  href="http://www.prettygoodterminal.com/download/freedownload.zip">here</a>.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```